# Как работает Наследование и область видимости в PHP?

Tags: php, ооп, наследование

```
<?php

class Bar
{
public function test() {
$this->testPrivate();
$this->testPublic();
}

public function testPublic() {
echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
}

private function testPrivate() {
echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
}
}

class Foo extends Bar
{
public function testPublic() {
echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
}

private function testPrivate() {
echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
}
}

$myFoo = new Foo();
$myFoo->test(); // Bar::testPrivate 
// Foo::testPublic
```

Паблик он берет из дочернего класса,
А приватный из своего.
Что совсем не логично.
Ведь он не может достать ПриватныйМетод. Ведь он не наследуется.

```
public function test() {
$this->testPrivate();//По сути в объекте нашего класса его нет, он же не наследуется, т.к. Приватное
$this->testPublic();
}
```

И это первый вопрос, каким образом это работает, **что вызывается метод, который не наследуется**, в других языках я вроде такого не встречал.

ВТОРОЕ.Я думал что т.к. я наследовал класс, то теперь типо test есть в моем наследованном классе, и он может работать со всеми моими методами. Но вызвать Приватный метод в дочернем классе он не может.

Comment: private - доступны только мне, protected - ещё и сыновьям, public - вообще всем подряд. Ну и static - даже когда помру :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `Foo` расширил класс `Bar`, унаследовал метод `test()` и перегрузил метод `testPrivate()`. Но т.к. данный метод `private`, он (перегруженный `testPrivate()`) вне области видимости класса `Bar`. По этой причине класс `Bar` вызывает тот `testPrivate()`, который видит - свой.

**upd:**

Вы не наследуете `test()` в абсолютном понимании этого термина. Слово **extends** переводится как **РАСШИРЯЕТ**, это оно и означает. Класс `Foo` **расширил** функционал класса `Bar`. `$myFoo` будет определятся `php` **и** как экземпляр класса `Bar`

```
$myFoo = new Foo();
echo ($myFoo instanceof Foo); //output = 1
echo ($myFoo instanceof Bar); //output = 1
```

**upd2:**

> До тех пор пока эти методы не будут переопределены, они будут сохранять свою исходную функциональность.
>   (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Методы с модификатором доступа `private` не перегружаются (не переопределяются).

**upd3:**

> ... Я спрашиваю почему они оказывается в объекте дочернего класса,
>   приватные методы и свойства ?

Они там не оказываются. Спросите себя, почему `test()` вообще был вызван? Потому, что интерпретатор сперва проверил родительский класс `Bar`, нашёл там `tect()`, далее проверил дочерний `Foo`, не нашёл там перегруженный `tect()` и начал интерпретировать `test()` в `Bar`. Далее, перейдя на `$this->testPrivate();` он, по той же схеме, нашёл данный метод в `Bar`, не нашёл (нашёл, но модификатором ему запрещено его выполнять, ведь он в данный момент в классе `Bar`) `private testPrivate()` и выполнил найденный.

[Хорошая статья вот](https://kp-room.ru/page/nasledovanie-php)

**upd4:**

Касаемо приватных свойств.

```
class Bar
{
    private $a = 'some';
}
class Foo extends Bar
{}
var_dump(new Foo);
// Foo Object
// (
//     [a:Bar:private] => some
// )
```

`[a:Bar:private] => some` не означает, что класс `Bar` содержит данное свойство. Это лишь указатель на то, что где-то в цепочке родителей класса `Foo` (в данном случае в `Bar`) есть приватное свойство. Собственно из записи дампа всё и так ясно.

> [`имя:`a:`класс:`Bar:`модификатор доступа:`private]

В памяти компьютера под класс создаётся структура `zend_class_entry`, среди полей которой есть `parent`- указатель (ссылка) на родителей данного класса. По этой ссылке в `var_dump` класса `Foo` попадает `private $a` класса `Bar`.

Очень в общем, но суть, думаю, ясна.

Comment: Вот только обьект я создал Foo. Поэтому откуда в нем берется доступ к приватному методу, которого типа нет.
при расширении класса дочерний класс наследует все общедоступные и защищенные методы из родительского класса. До тех пор пока эти методы не будут переопределены, они будут сохранять свою исходную функциональность.
Если вникнуть в документацию, то она говорит что это.
Но если посмотреть исходник обьекта, то можно увидеть в нем Приватные свойства и методы родительского класса.

Comment: Я понимаю что расширили. Но каким образом оно может доставать Приватный метод сверху.

Comment: class A {
    private $a = 1;
}
 
class B extends A {}
 
print_r( new A ); // A Object ( [a:A:private] => 1 )
print_r( new B ); // B Object ( [a:A:private] => 1 )  

По идеи так не должно быть

Comment: Я спрашиваю почему они оказывается в обьекте дочернего класса, приватные методы и свойства ? Выше пример кидал.

Comment: КАК НЕ ОКАЗЫВАЕТСЯ, если я вам скинул код, и в вардамп ОН ЕСТЬ.

B Object ( [a:A:private] => 1 )

Comment: Object ( [a:A:private] => 1 )  Шта?

Comment: Вот что, в Классе B вардамп есть приватное свойство класса А
class A { private $a = 1; } 
class B extends A {} 
print_r( new A ); // A Object ( [a:A:private] => 1 )
 print_r( new B ); // B Object ( [a:A:private] => 1 )

Comment: Это всё как-то относится к примеру из вашего вопроса?

Comment: Да, я ведь спрашиваю, почему ПРИВАТНЫЕ МЕТОДЫ И СВОЙСТВА попадают в обьект наследника. В документации об этом ни слова. Но они там есть

Comment: Обновил ответ. Надеюсь, с пользой)

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков Спасибо за интересный вопрос. Я думаю, что как верно написал Кирилл, не нужно понимать это наследованием, это расширение. И, видимо, смотреть нужно снизу-вверх (от родителей), а не наоборот. Так как test() инициализирован в родительском классе, то оттуда он и вызывается. Далее он смотрит вверх, и либо находит доступные переопределения методов, либо нет. В вашем примере он не находит их, так как в зону видимости родительского класса не попадает private класс потомка.

Answer (score -1):

[Документация по PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.inheritance.php):

> Например, при расширении класса дочерний класс наследует все общедоступные и защищенные методы из родительского класса. До тех пор пока эти методы не будут переопределены, они будут сохранять свою исходную функциональность.

Определите методы `testPrivate()` не `private`, а `protected`.